# Being homeomorphic is a relation between two topological spaces. How to understand the result that any open interval is homeomorphic to R?

Tags: general-topology

The interval $(a,b)$ and $\mathbb R$ are not topological spaces, they are just sets.

Does the statement "$(a,b)$ and $\mathbb R$ are homeomorphic" mean that for any topology $\mathcal T_1$ on $(a,b)$ and any topology $\mathcal T_2$ on $\mathbb R$, the topological spaces $((a,b), \mathcal T_1)$ and $(\mathcal R, \mathcal T_2)$ are homeomorphic?

Homeomorphism is between two topology space. (a,b) and R are not topology space when  $\tau_{(a,b)}$ and $\tau_{\mathbb{R}}$ haven't been specified. Do they mean that (a,b) and R are homeomorphic for any topology when they say that (a,b) and R are homeomorphic? But I don't think it's right. So, what do they mean?

Comment: When they say that $(a,b)$ and $\Bbb R$ are homeomorphic, they mean with their standard topologies, i.e. $$\tau_{\Bbb R}=\{U\subseteq\Bbb R\,:\,\forall x\in U,\exists\varepsilon>0,\forall y\in(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon), y\in U\}$$ and $\tau_{(a,b)}$ the subspace topology induced by $\tau_{\Bbb R}$ $$\tau_{(a,b)}=\{X\subseteq (a,b)\,:\, \exists U\in\tau_{\Bbb R}, X=(a,b)\cap U\}$$

Comment: Welcome. What do you mean, they are "not topology space"? They *are* topological spaces when viewed under the natural topology. They are also homeomorphic, yes. This is an unclearly written question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

This is an example of an [abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation): it's extremely common in mathematics to name a topological space $X$ by naming a set and leaving the topology to be implicitly deduced from context, and in particular if $X$ is a subset of a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ then the implicitly chosen topology is usually the subspace topology with respect to the Euclidean topology. So when people say that $\mathbb{R}$ and $(a, b)$ are homeomorphic they mean with the Euclidean topology and the subspace topology with respect to the Euclidean topology, respectively.

> Does the statement "$(a,b)$ and $\mathbb R$ are homeomorphic" mean that for any topology $\mathcal T_1$ on $(a,b)$ and any topology $\mathcal T_2$ on $\mathbb R$, the topological spaces $((a,b), \mathcal T_1)$ and $(\mathcal R, \mathcal T_2)$ are homeomorphic?

No, this is obviously false. If you don't give them the Euclidean topologies then they're just two uncountable sets, and of course an uncountable set can have many non-homeomorphic topologies on it. Why even bother naming them $\mathbb{R}$ and $(a, b)$ if you just wanted to name two uncountable sets?